# What was the cost of photo development in the ’60s, in France?

Tags: film, developing, history, paper

Could anyone tell me how much it approximately cost to develop a roll of film and its photos onto "standard" paper format in the ’60s in France, for the general public?

Comment: Have you looked around on the web? Anything you've found that was not helpful? Please [edit] your question to include any prior research. This helps others to understand what you've done so far, why that didn't answer your question and prevents  that others suggest the same (unhelpful) information.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke: Of course, I've made a lot of searches, but just found nothing informative nor relevant to the question (the reason why I post here). So nothing useful to list here.

Comment: I think listing things you've tried, even if they have no result, is useful nonetheless. It can reveal aspects of the question which you have not included in the text. No need to list all websearches, but something along the lines of "I've looked for X, Y, Z on sited 1,2,3, but found only information such as <link> which does not answer my question because...".

Answer (score 1):

In the United States Color Negative Film $1.00 to develop roll film $0.29 to make a print on paper. Black & White Film $0.25 to develop roll film $0.10 to make a print on paper.

Price in Europe similar based on the exchange rate of that era.

Comment: Thank you ! Wow, I guess this was really "underpriced" (or reallistic ?) compared to France. In the very last years of argentic developing in France, near 2010, the lowest price on the market was 1 French Franc (about 15 actual US cents) to develop one photo onto paper. I guess 50 years before, the price was really much higher. Or not. :)

Comment: I am 84 years old. I worked in a giant photofinishing lab in the 1960's. I became Technical Manager for Photofinishing for Eckerd Drugs. We had 2000 drugstores, and 7 giant photofinishing plants each sized to develop and print 20,000 rolls of film a day. Price paid for photofinishing remained the same or lowered due to equipment improvements which reduced labor needs. All over the world, photofinishing was kept low in cost to lure customers into the drugstore, same in Europe I know for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: Hi @Oliver. 2010 was _not_ the very last days of "argentic" developing in France - film photography is still alive. By the way, "argentic" is not an English word. The English translation of "photographie argentique" is just "film photography", or if you must, "analogue photography". It's probably also worth pointing out - to be precise, photos are not developed onto photo paper - they are _printed_ onto photo paper. It's a 2-step process - develop the film, print the photos - commonly (in the past?) called "D&P"

Comment: @osullic: well, when I was talking about last days, I meant the last large evolution of general public prices. Now, it remains a niche market. Talking about printing or developing, well, I really don't know how it's done in the photo industry, but I supposed, visibly wrong, that they where in fact developed. As we was doing it in a black room, the same as the film itself.